# R - choose the number which appears most in a row

Tags: r

I have a df `test`:

```
A   B   C
1   1   NA
2   NA  NA
1   2   2
```

I want to create a another column, say `test$D`, which is the number that appears most in that row, excluding NA. My desired df is:

```
A   B   C   D
1   1   NA  1
2   NA  NA  2
1   2   2   2
```

I have been looking for a similar function like `rowMeans` with na.rm=T but could not find any appropriate function for this situation. Really appreciate any help

Comment: Another option if there are only numbers from 0:9 are `(0:9)[max.col(sapply(as.character(0:9), str_count, string = do.call(paste, c(test, sep=","))))]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to find the frequency of numbers in each row and get the maximum frequency number using `which.max`

```
test$D <- apply(test, 1, FUN = function(x) {
        x1 <- table(factor(x, levels = unique(x)))
          as.numeric(names(x1)[which.max(x1)])})
test$D
#[1] 1 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option using `table`,

```
apply(test, 1, function(i) as.numeric(names(sort(-table(i)))[1]))
#[1] 1 2 2
```